# how to insert a node/folder in a JTree in swing?

Tags: java, swing

I tried to insert a folder under the "root folder" , but instead of going under root folder it was stored under a "sub root folder". Below is my code. I couldn't find the problem. so need a little help.

```
private void bAddtnameActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
         lMessage.setText("");
         DefaultTreeModel model = (DefaultTreeModel) tWorld.getModel();
         DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) model.getRoot();
         if(!tfTname.getText().trim().equals(""))
         {
           node.add(new DefaultMutableTreeNode(tfTname.getText()));
           model.reload();
         } else {
               lMessage.setText("Team name can't be left Blank.");
         }          
    }
```

Comment: Show how you construct your `DefaultTreeModel`, seems problem in that, because `node.add(...)` must work properly.

Comment: Sorry Sir, didn't get you. I'm kinda new to Swing, but I think DefaultTreeModel is a predefined class for the JTree. Not sure, but I think so.